# Removing other modules of Maven Profile from Project Directory of IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-profiles

I have created a multi-module maven project and I want to have two profiles, which I've declared as below.

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>bootstrap-server</id>
     <modules>
      <module>./bootstrapserver</module>
     </modules>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>file-search</id>
      <modules>
       <module>./filesearch</module>
       <module>./webservice</module>
      </modules>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I choose, for an example, `file-search` profile, IntelliJ builds the profile fine (Using integrated maven panel in IntelliJ) and it builds only the two modules I've specified, which is the required behaviour. It works well for the other profile as well.

However, when I choose one profile, the directories of the modules in other profiles remain in the project structure window, as displayed below.

[image: When I choose the <code>file=search</code> profile]

The image above shows how IntelliJ shows the project structure when I activate `file-search` profile.

Can I configure IntelliJ to remove the modules displayed in the Project window which are not used in one profile? For an example, if I select `file-search` module, I want to remove `bootstrapserver` module from the Project panel since it's not being used when developing under `file-search` profile.

Thank you.

Comment: You usually don't put modules into profiles. So I doubt there is any support for that.

Comment: never do such things cause it produces many issues https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/ like the ones you already facing in IDEA IntelliJ apart from that what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `For an example, if I select file-search module, I want to remove bootstrapserver module from the Project panel since it's not being used when developing under file-search profile.` - the module is removed from the project structure as you can see in project view it is not bolded and the directory does not have module indicator. But files in this case are still displayed in project view.